# Android 7.0 Animations are not working properly (alpha, duration, delay)

Tags: java, android, animation, android-animation, android-7.0-nougat

After upgrading my phone from Android 6.0 to 7.0 animations aren't working how they are supposed to work.

I have small class for Animations in my project with 3 simple static methods:

```
public static Animation fadeInAnimation(int duration, int offset)
{
    Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
    animation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    animation.setDuration(duration);
    animation.setStartOffset(offset);

    return animation;
}

public static Animation fadeOutAnimation(int duration, int offset)
{
    Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);
    animation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    animation.setDuration(duration);
    animation.setStartOffset(offset);

    return animation;
}

public static Animation fadeInOutAnimation(int duration, int repeatCount, int repeatMode, int offset)
{
    Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
    animation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    animation.setRepeatCount(repeatCount);
    animation.setRepeatMode(repeatMode);
    animation.setDuration(duration);
    animation.setStartOffset(offset);

    return animation;
}
```

In SplashScreen class i was using them this way:

```
mAnimationScreenStart = Animations.fadeInAnimation(1500, 300);
mAnimationScreenEnd = Animations.fadeOutAnimation(1500, 0);
textView.startAnimation(Animations.fadeInOutAnimation(ANIMATION_DURATION, Animation.INFINITE, Animation.REVERSE, ANIMATION_OFFSET));
```

TextView is a "Tap to continue" text and it's working just fine.
Then i'm adding listeners for both animations. Everything was ok on Android 6.0, but on 7.0 duration is behaving like a delay, not like actual animation duration.

So then i tried to do animations without my previous class, like this:

```
frameLayout.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(3000).setStartDelay(350).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter()
    {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation)
        {
            super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
            frameLayout.setAlpha(1f);

            frameLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    if (!isClicked)
                    {
                        isClicked = true;
                        frameLayout.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(3000).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation)
                            {
                                super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                                frameLayout.setAlpha(0f);

                                Intent intentLogin = new Intent(StartScreen.this, Login.class);
                                startActivity(intentLogin);
                                finish();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

isClicked is just a boolean to make sure that ending animation won't be repeated.

But still, animations are not working properly. There IS animation but it's duration is like 0,5 sec and duration i set is behaving like delay. I've tried thing like frameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) and many others. I've searched on net if it's problem with Android 7.0 but i coudn't find anything.

As i said, on 6.0 animations were working properly without any problems.

I would be really glad for help with this thing.